# Firebase multiple redirects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase domain `name.com`. In the hosting section, I have a redirect setup `name.com`->`www.name.com`. However, once I input `http://name.com` into [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) it shows multiple redirects happening, all of them combined taking > 1s.

The redirects go as follows:

1. `http://name.com`->`https://name.com`
2. `https://name.com`->`https://www.name.com`

Is there a way to combine these to a single redirect?
Or should I look for other ways to optimize my redirect time? If so, what ways would that be?

Thank you.